# How to Retrieve image in db2 using worklight 's adapter

Tags: db2, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I develop worklight app. So I install db2 express-c v.10 on linux server and create table "Promotion" and have column below

```
promotionId          VARCHAR(15)
promotionDescription VARCHAR(100)
fromDate             DATE
toDate               DATE
img                  VARCHAR(100)
```

then I store img column as path of image on linux server like "/img/BigC_Promotion/1.jpg"
So, can I retrive image using Image's path and fill in src properties for example,

```
<img src='/img/BigC_Promotion/1.jpg' />
```

I install on window 7 on my laptop

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you just have to concatenate the value:

```
select '<img src=''' || img ''' />'
from Promotion
where xxx
```

You could also get the same via Xquery.

If the path is readable by the Webserver, it can access the resource and show the image in the browser.